# What happens if your server's maximum player limit is 0?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have a Minecraft server and I am wondering what is supposed to happen if your Minecraft server's maximum player limit is 0?

The other day, I joined a server with '0' maximum players and it let me join the server. Another server had a maximum of '1' but there were actually 84 players in the server. (mc.good-gaming.com)

What does setting this value do? How was I able to join these servers if the player count was higher than the maximum?

Comment: I would assume nobody could join?

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't just do it and find out, and instead asked someone else to do it and find out? Like, is there a larger problem here that we're supposed to be solving?

Comment: Yeah, [it looks like maybe you *do* have an unspoken, hidden question under this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/293095/what-happens-if-your-servers-maximum-player-limit-is-0?noredirect=1#comment413950_293097). You should probably [edit] your question to ask directly what you really want to know about.

Comment: Programmers tend to use a value of `-1` to represent 'an unlimited amount'. If -1 is not an option, you're stuck using whatever values are accepted by the program.

Comment: @KWA21BT No-one is forcing you to edit. But editing is the only way the question will be reopened at this point. It looks like it's already receiving votes to be *deleted* too, so editing might also help avoid that. If you want help, you might reconsider how you respond to basic attempts to help you help us understand your question.

Comment: I have edited in what seems to be the underlying question based on the comments on the answer below. I have also cleaned up the comments here on the question. @KWA21BT - Please don't lash out at people that are only trying to help you get the *actual answer* you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You won't be able to join and neither will anyone else (I tested this).  It will say that the server is full, which makes sense.  Here's why:

The `max-players` in the sever properties file takes an integer.  It can be between 0 and 2,147,483,647.  The [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Server.properties) states that the `max-players` property is how many players can play on the server **at the same time**:

> The maximum number of players that can play on the server at the same time.

So, if 0 players are allowed on the server at the same time, then no one can play on the server.

Comment: This is a correct answer, but not the correct answer for a 1 server. In a other day, I simply join a server with 0 players maximum and then it would let me join the server. And also, it thinks players that are maximum to 0 (that is 1 server) is infinite.

Comment: @KWA21BT I can't really understand what you are trying to say in your comment, but I was not able to join my server when I set the player limit to 0 as expected.  What is a "1 server?"

Comment: You dont understand my comments? Actually, why on earth does the server has a maximum of 1 and then 84 players in this minecraft server. mc.good-gaming.com

Comment: @KWA21BT That's a custom Minecraft server that has no player limit. But because it has to tell your Server List screen a player maximum even if it doesn't have a maximum, it lies and says 1. Some other custom servers say 0. Ideally it would say ∞, but the Minecraft client doesn't support showing that, so it can't and it has to be a number of some kind. If you have a Minecraft server with a hosting service and you're trying to get infinite players, you should probably clarify your question so we can explain how that works in more detail.